# gfx 970 drivers not working

Tags: drivers

I downloaded the latest gtx 970 drivers and tried to run them. It doesn't work because of Server x running. So I press Ctrl alt f1 and type sudo service lightdm stop and try again. It runs, I click accept on the licence agreement then hit another error. 'The nouvaeu driver is currently in use on your system and the driver is incompatible with the nvidea driver'. Google said to blacklist nouvaeu in the blacklist.conf file in etc/modprobe.d folder. I did that. It then says in this guide I was reading to rebuild the initramfs file by moving it from boot/initramfs-$usernams.IMG to .bak. And I couldn't find the file. I reboot and get a black screen of death. Can't even break into terminal. Nightmare! Help me

Comment: Okay we can help but may require a bit more information. So I gather you are having problems finding a compatable driver for Nvidia. That is common, Nvidia does that. Are you sure you are using the correct driver? As far as the boot issue goes, can you boot to recovery from the grub? If so post the output of `ls -la /boot` You can also uninstall the nvidia drivers from recovery if they are what caused the crashes.

Comment: Can you tell me what is a grub. And yea I had the latest drivers. Also how do i uninstall drivers from the recovery? I've formatted my machine so many times to try get this working. Is it quicker to do what you are asking by formatting again? I also find it bizarre that when I format and put a fresh Ubuntu install on there that I even get an error that it wants me to send off yo the developers. It asks me that every time I start the system

Comment: By having the latest drivers I obviously meant I had them downloaded and uninstalled since I can't get the driver working.

Comment: Surely someone here has a gtx 970 and knows how to get this working.

Answer (score 0):

I had a very simular situation a couple years ago, with a simular nvidia card. When you installed Ubuntu, how did it run from the live disk? Grub is the bootloader. Press right shift while booting until a screen comes up with boot options, select Ubuntu (recovery mode). From there select "drop to a root shell", and than remount your hard disc as read/wite:

```
mount -o remount,rw /
```

Now let's get rid of all the Nvidia drivers:

```
apt-get purge nvidia* && apt-get update && reboot
```

.
See what happens. The system will boot and try to use Novuea (however you spell it) which is the default nvidia open source driver, i think. With that card, IIRC, you may want to try the Nvidia 331 driver. If that does not work, perhaps one from the Xorg guy's repo:

```
ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

When you installed Ubuntu, how did it run from the live disk?

[This thread](http://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2262451) suggests perhaps the 304 driver would work for you. Basically, Nvidia cards are *really* finicky. If you install the wrong one than the machine sometimes fails to boot at all. (I am pretty sure I've seen a video of Lynis Torvalds himself tell nvidia straight up that they suck) ... but there is a driver that will work for you, unless your system is really, really old. What kind of processor do you have btw?

Comment: No I'm trying to install Ubuntu properly. I will try the suggestions tonight.  I'm running 15.04 Ubuntu.  If all fails I can also try using Ubuntu 14 too. Will update this post tonight with my test v

Comment: Ok I have just formatted again and trying this. I will do the first 2 steps and reboot. No idea what the 3rd command is or how to use it, so i will skip that bit

Comment: Ok the commands worked, but it's still using the default driver which doesn't work properly. So I've got nowhere. Also what is an IIRC and how do i install the 331 driver, and also how do i use that ppa command. My pc is younger than 2 years old with an 3570k processor

Comment: Ok I formatted again and tried to do the steps he in said in the "this thread" link below. This didn't work either.
apt-get update
apt-get install nvidia-331

Comment: Maybe you need a more recent driver than. I believe NVIDIA has a list of what drivers work on which cards on their site.

Answer (score 0):

This is not a good idea to install drivers from Nvidia site and blacklist nouveau manually. Even if they install correctly after first kernel update you will get a black screen.

The best way to install new Nvidia drivers is from xorg-edgers ppa.

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-346
sudo add-apt-repository -r ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
```

Comment: Formatted again. Did these steps and rebooted. Ubuntu wouldn't boot, it got stuck at the 4 loading bars just before the login screen usually appears. It's worth noting that the default driver is x.org x server -- nouveau display driver from xserver-xorg-video-nouvear (open source). Also when I format using this new card. On my new install i always get 'sorry ubuntu 15.04 has experienced an internal error'. It says the 'ExecuteablePath' is /usr/lib/unity-settings-daemon/unity-settings-daemon'. This causes a noticeable delay on boot at the login page compared to when i used my old graphics card